# In My ERC-721 Contract, tokenURI Doesn't Return A String, It Returns A Promise

Tags: erc-721, ethers.js, hardhat, openzeppelin-contracts, memory

In my solidity contract, the function for tokenURI looks like this:

```
function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
  public
  view
  virtual
  override
  returns (string memory)
{
  require(
    _exists(tokenId),
    "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token"
  );
  
  if (revealed == false) {
    return string(notRevealedUri);
  }

  string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
  return
    bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
    ? string(
      abi.encodePacked(
        currentBaseURI,
        tokenId.toString(),
        baseExtension
      )
    )
  : "";
}
```

Notice that I have a bool to determine whether or not the "revealed" tokenURI has been set. The problem I've having is when `revealed` is set to false but I have called the `setNotRevealedURI` function to actually set the `notRevealedUri` to a value. I want the function `tokenURI` to give me this `notRevealedUri` string but instead it gives me a Promise:

```js
> token.tokenURI(1);
Promise {
  <pending>,
  [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 501,
  [Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol)]: 7,
  [Symbol(destroyed)]: { destroyed: false }
}
>
```

I've been interacting with the contract using hardhat btw.

So how do I get this function to output a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All contract interactions are asynchronous, you will need to use `await` or `then`.

```js
await token.tokenURI(1);
```